# Disable directory access other than server block

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

My nginx server block

```
server {
listen     80;
root /var/www/html/blog;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
```

server running wordpress. I want to limit PHP to access /var/www/html/blog only. Request to access other directory like /var/www/html/web will be blocked.

What I've tried-

```
location ~ ^/(?!(blog)/?) { 
    deny all;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
}
```

How to do that?

Comment: If you have `root /var/www/html/blog;` then `/var/www/html/web` is outside the document root. You do not need to deny it, it is already inaccessible.

Comment: But php can access it. if i call include_once('/var/www/html/web/index.php') then it can include it

Comment: PHP doesn't use Nginx to access the file system, so Nginx cannot prevent PHP from using `include_once` to find files outside the document root.

Comment: You may need to run PHP in a chroot-ed environment. This may be helpful - https://www.vennedey.net/resources/3-Secure-webspaces-with-NGINX-PHP-FPM-chroots-and-Lets-Encrypt